# Как установить инстаграмную ленту в виде карусели на сайт?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, slider, instagram

Раньше у меня на сайте использовалась бесплатная карусель инстаграмной ленты от сервиса [snapwidget](https://snapwidget.com/widgets/create?plan=free&service=instagram&type=grid) С некоторых же пор этот сервис заблокировал возможность бесплатной карусели сделав эту услугу платной..
Вот интересуюсь - есть ли альтернатива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нашел [плагин Enjoy Plugin for Instagram для wordpress](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/enjoy-instagram-instagram-responsive-images-gallery-and-carousel/screenshots/)
Единственное, что пока не могу разобраться, как зациклить карусель